# Evaluate: $\arcsin(\sin \frac{\pi}{3})$

Tags: calculus

$\arcsin(\sin \frac{\pi}{3})$

I had this question on a test today. I was a little stumped when it asked me to evaulate. I hope I at least attempted to answer it right.

my answer is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{\pi}{3}})^2}.$$

Comment: Are you sure its $\sin^{-1}$ and not $\cos^{-1}$?

Comment: $\arcsin$ and $\sin$ are inverses to one another.

Comment: $f^{-1} \circ f(x) = x$.

Answer (score 4):

For $|x| \leq \pi/2$, we have that $$\arcsin(\sin(x)) = x.$$

Since $\pi/3 \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, $$\arcsin(\sin(\pi/3)) = \pi/3.$$

Answer (score 0):

We can first calculate that $$\sin\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}.$$
Then, you should know that $\arcsin$ is the inverse function of $\sin$, which means that if $\sin(x)=y$ then $\arcsin(y)=x$. However, what we should be careful about is the domain of $\arcsin$, which is $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Get back to your question, in this certian one, $y=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\in[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. So $\arcsin(y)=x=\frac{\pi}{3}$. And, it is a pity that your own answer is wrong.

Comment: The *domain* of arcsin is all complex numbers – or, if we exclude complex results, [-1,1].  Its *range* is [-pi/2, pi/2].  At least as I learned those terms forty-some years ago.

Comment: To produce $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, $\cot x$, $\arcsin x$, $\arccos x$, $\arctan x$, type \sin x, \cos x, \tan x, \csc x, \sec x, \cot x, \arcsin x, \arccos x, \arctan x, respectively, in math mode.

Answer (score 0):

Cancelling two opposite trig functions you get first answer $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

For inverse sine, include $\pi- \frac{\pi}{3}$.

Next add $2 n\pi$ to either for all the co-terminal angles due to vector rotation.

Comment: The range of the arcsine function is $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.